# Query String authentication htaccess apache

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite

I have the set of codes in my htaccess file. The aim is to require user authentication when someone access the wp-login.php file. However, I would like the flexibility to disable authentication when a query string "action=postpass" is used.

So for example, if I use enters:
http://domain.com/wp-login.php    - An authentication box appears
http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=postpass    - No authentication box appears.

It appears that Apache executed mod_auth module before mod_rewrite. So at the moment, as long as the user calls up on the wp-login.php, an authentication box appears.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)?(domain.com) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?wp-login\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=postpass [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=NoAuth,L]

AuthUserFile "/home/passwd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=NoAuth
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do what you want using those tools.  Sorry.

What you're doing doesn't work because authentication rules are processed before rewrite rules, regardless of how you order them in `.htaccess`.  This is counterintuitive.  Let's look at a quick example.

When the page is loaded, the authentication rules are processed first.  At that time, the `RewriteRule` has not yet been evaluated.  Therefore `NoAuth` is not set.  Therefore `Allow from env=NoAuth` doesn't let anyone in.  After the authentication rules have been processed, the URL is rewritten (in your case it's unchanged, but that doesn't matter) and `NoAuth` is defined, but the access rules are not re-evaluated so it's irrelevant.

There is no good simple way to get `QUERY_STRING` data for authentication.  It's a kluge, but `SetEnvIf` could work.  You could use a `RewriteRule` to first rewrite requests with a certain `QUERY_STRING` and put something notable in the `URI` and then add a second `SetEnvIf` to check for that URI.  If only `SetEnvIf` could access the query string, this would be one step, but it can't, so it's two.